# Entrenar red neuronal(Dudas)

Tags: dataset, inteligencia-artificial

lo mas seguro es que no tenga claro el proceso de entrenamiento de una red neuronal pero me salto una duda.

He Leido muchos post de gente que tiene problemas con el tamaño de su data set, que por ello no pueden entrenar a la red.(Aqui viene las pregunta, si es una tonteria no me linchen porfavor).

Por que cargan todo el data set directo a la memoria?
Por que no guardan las matrices de pesos por ejemplo y van entrenando de poco en poco en vez de cargar todo el dataset a la memoria?
Es posible lo que planteo, el guardar las matrices de pesos en un archivo por ejemplo y retomarlo despues o afecta el proceso de entrenamiento?

Gracia

Answer (score 1):

Lo que se hace en estos casos suele ser cargar el dataset en batches y pasarlo a tu red neuronal para que vaya entrenando, poco a poco. Imaginemos que tienes un dataset de 60.000 imágenes, hay varias opciones para tú resolver tú problema (en Python)

1. Si es en tú ordenador de casa, tienes que hacer lo que se conoce como Pandas Incremental. Esto es crearte una función que vaya leyendo tu datasets en batches. De tal forma que, en el ejemplo anterior, cogeríamos las 3000 primeras imágenes, las leeríamos, se las pasaríamos como input a la red neuronal para que entrene, después volvemos a hacer lo mismo con otras 3000, así hasta llegar a 60.000
2. Hay otra opción para hacer lo mismo que en el punto 1 y que es más optima, con una librería que se llama Dask. Esta librería te permite trabajar tanto en tú ordenador, como en la nube de forma distribuida si lo deseas, y resuelve gran parte de los problemas, que en Pandas los tienes que resolver de forma más manual creándote funciones.
3. Trabajar con Pyspark con un cluster distribuido (lo más normal es que sea en la nube) entrenando la red neuronal.

**Trabajar en Local vs trabajar en la nube:**

- Trabajar en local: lo puedes hacer con Pandas o con Dask, y esta pensado para medium data (datasets que su peso máximo es 1TB y por tanto caben en disco)
- Trabajar en la nube: para datasets que pesan más de 1TB es obligatorio trabajar en la nube ya que está solución esta pensada para cantidades de datos enormes (Big Data)